# SQL design for performance

Tags: sql, performance

I am new to SQL and I have a basic question about performance.

I want to create a users database which will store information about my users:

- Id
- Log in name
- Password
- Real name

Later I want to perform a `SELECT` query on: Id, Log in name and Real name.

What would be the best design for this database, what tables and what keys should I create?

Comment: I think you kind of hit it - key would be Id (which will automatically be an index), then add an index on login name and real name. The one thing you might do is break real name to lastname and firstname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only about those 4 fields it looks like just one table. Primary key on `ID`, unique index on `LoginName`. You may not want to store the password, but only a hash.

Depending on your queries, create different indexes. Furthermore, you may not need the `ID` field at all.

**UPDATE:**
Creating an index on certain column(s) enables the database to optimize its SQL statements. Given your user table:

```
USER
    USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
    LOGIN_ID VARCHAR(<size>) NOT NULL
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(<size>) NOT NULL
    NAME VARCHAR(<size>) NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT PK_USER PRIMARY KEY ( USER_ID )
```

The databases I know will automatically create an index on the primary key, which in fact means that the database maintains an optimized lookup table, see [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) for further details.

Now say, you want to query users by `LOGIN_ID` which is a fairly common use case, I guess, you can create another index like:

```
CREATE INDEX I_USER_1 ON USER ( LOGIN_ID asc )
```

The above index will optimize the `select * from USER where LOGIN_ID='foo'`. Furthermore, you can create a unique index instead, assuming that you do not want duplicate `LOGIN_ID`s:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_USER_1 ON USER ( LOGIN_ID asc )
```

That's the whole story, so if you want to optimize a query for the users real name (`NAME`), you just create another index:

```
CREATE INDEX I_USER_2 ON USER ( NAME asc )
```

Comment: What about the query on the "Real name"? And can you tell me what is happening behind the scene when I am indexing the login name? What sql is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the @homes answer you should work out what sort of queries you will be running and then optimize for those sorts of queries.  For example if you are doing a lot of writes and not as many reads having lots of indexes can cause performance issues.  It's a bit like tuning an engine for a car, are you going to be going quickly down a drag strip or are you tuning it for driving long distances.

Anyway you also asked about the NAME column.  If you are going to be matching on a varchar column it might be worth investigating the use of FULLTEXT Indexes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx

This allows you to do optimized searchs on names where you might be matching parts of a name and the like.  As the @homes answer said it really does depend on what your queries and intent is when writing the query.

Might be worth making the table and using the query execution plan in something like SQL management studio against your queries and see what impact your indexes have on the amount of rows and sort of looks up that are happening.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/

Comment: When referencing another answer, it's better to link to it (say saying "@homes answer") than refer to "the answer above". Answers can move relative to each other, another answer could appear above yours, etc.